# disable button via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

here is the my code;

Loading data from database my buttons,after loading finished,I want to
                              trigger some client script,.in my senario,after clicked the first button ,want to disable clicked button,
                              and enable the secon button(clickable element)
                              I am able to disabled fisrt button,
                              I couldnt enable secont button though
                              **

First button

```
 <button type="button"  class="btn  btn-default" 
                              onclick=" 
                              var resetbtnid = '#m-' + $(this).attr('id'); //I am getting 


                              $(this).prop('disabled', true);
                              $('#resetbtnid').removeAttr('disabled');

                              "
                             name='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Fiyat") %>'
                             id='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Id") %>' >
                             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span></button>
```

Second button

```
 <button type="button" disabled="disabled"  class="btn btn-default"
    id='m-<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Id") %>' 
    name='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Fiyat") %>' >
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></span></button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector is incorrect. In your code `$('resetbtnid').removeAttr('disabled')`

Use `#` if you want ID selector like `$('#resetbtnid').removeAttr('disabled')`

You can use `.prop()` like `$('#resetbtnid').prop('disabled', true/false)`

Use `.` for class selector.

EDIT:

As `resetbtnid` is a variable use it without quotes

```
 var resetbtnid = '#m-' + $(this).attr('id'); 
 $(resetbtnid).removeAttr('disabled');
```

Comment: @user2460637, use `$(resetbtnid).removeAttr('disabled');`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

//Enable

```
$('#buttonID').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

//Disable

```
$('#buttonID').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Comment: need eabled not disabled

Comment: Sorry the question's title told me that!:)

Answer (score 1):

When there are two buttons, one is enabled (default), the second is disabled, it looks like this in code

HTML:

```
<button id="btn1" />
<button id="btn2" disabled="disabled" />
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btn1').click(function () {
            $('#btn1').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('#btn2').prop('disabled', false);
        })
    })
```

That should do the job!